# what is the value of the acceleration of a bar magnet falling through a coil?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

when a bar magnet is made to fall through a closed circular coil kept horizontally,according to Faraday's law an emf is induced in the coil,which again according to Lenz law,will oppose the downward motion of the magnet.Therefore the value of the acceleration changes.What is the value of this acceleration,or what is the equation describing the motion of the magnet?

Answer (score 0):

When the magnet approaches the coil the current induced in the coil will repel the approaching magnet, so acceleration of the magnet is less than that of acceleration due to gravity. When the magnet has passed through the coil then it is attracted by the coil in accordance with Lenz's law hence its acceleration is again less than $g$. Try working it out yourself

Comment: I knew the acceleration decreases.I want to know the math,the value of it if the field strength of the magnet and other quantities given.

Comment: solve using the equations i posted below

Answer (score -2):

[image] Use these equations to get the desired mathematical result, try it yourself

Comment: The value of B you are giving is from Biot Savart Law.Is it valid for induction too?